# How to center All position element in div

Tags: html, css

I have `.child_div` element and it have absolute items so i want to centered inside my `.child_div` (green background) element properly.

```css
.parent_div {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.child_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.item1 {
  background: orange;
  left: 20%;
}

.item2 {
  background: yellow;
  left: 25%;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
  left: 30%;
}

.item4 {
  background: red;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do the `.item`'s it need to be positioned absolute?

Comment: it doesn't matter why items need to be position absolute.they must be overlap that's why need to be absolute

Comment: You don't need to position absolute your .item class. You have already defined a flex container and align it's item center. so if you remove position absolute it qill work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `position: absolute` and unnecessary `margin` and `left` values, you get the desired result.

**Edit** - To overlap, use `position: relative` and `left` values.

```css
.parent_div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 1200px;
}

.child_div {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.item1 {
  background: orange;
}

.item2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is something that you don't understand my items must overlap

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `display:inline-block` and `text-align: center`.

```css
.parent_div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 1200px;
  text-align:center;
}

.child_div {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.item1 {
  background: orange;
  left: 20%;
}

.item2 {
  background: yellow;
  left: 25%;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
  left: 30%;
}

.item4 {
  background: red;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```